# Swift: How to airplay video using AVKit to Apple TV when AirPlay Device is Connected and Mirroring is Off

Tags: ios, swift, airplay, television

> **Apple TV** is connected on same WiFi network. AirPlay device is shown as Connected on AirPlay Picker. Video playing but only when mirroring is turned on.
>
> Screens array count is 2 only when mirroring is turned on. Is there a way to display contents on Apple TV without even turning on mirroring.

How do I get Screen count 2 without turning on Mirroring on iOS device.

**Here is my code:**

```
func checkForExistingScreenAndInitializeIfPresent() {
    print("\n Total Displays Available:-:- \(UIScreen.screens().count)")        
    if UIScreen.screens().count > 1 {
        // Get the screen object that represents the external display.
        let secondScreen: UIScreen = UIScreen.screens()[1]
        let screenBounds: CGRect = secondScreen.bounds
        self.secondWindow = UIWindow(frame: screenBounds)
        self.secondWindow!.screen = secondScreen
        self.secondWindow!.hidden = false
        let airplayName: String = self.activeAirplayOutputRouteName()
        print("\n External Displays:- \(airplayName) :- Connected")
        print("\n Total Displays Available:- \(UIScreen.screens().count)")
        print("\(airplayName) bounds : \(secondScreen.nativeBounds)")  
    } 
}

func activeAirplayOutputRouteName() -> String {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let currentRoute: AVAudioSessionRouteDescription = appDelegate.audioSession.currentRoute
    for outputPort: AVAudioSessionPortDescription in currentRoute.outputs {
        if (outputPort.portType == AVAudioSessionPortAirPlay) {
            return outputPort.portName
        }
    }
    return ""
}
```

Comment: Hi again Jitendra. Found a solution?

Comment: No, we have developed a separate app for Apple TV and we are communicating between IOS Device and Apple TV. Just pass URL to Apple TV to let Apple TV play the URL on Apple TV without any mirroring. @TheCrazyProfessor

Comment: Omg, how could I miss understand this question so much! If I understand your right you wanna add the Airplay bottom to your video player so you can choose to Airplay the video without the need for turning Mirroring on?

Comment: @TheCrazyProfessor Hi! Do you know how to add Airplay button to video so I can airplay it without mirroring on?

Comment: @Said-AbdullaAtkaev only know how to do it with Javascript https://stackoverflow.com/a/39880467/4691734

Comment: @TheCrazyProfessor nice!

Comment: @Said-AbdullaAtkaev So sorry, it's was the wrong link, here is the right one. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13655237/airplay-with-custom-html5-controls